# Looping through space separated list in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.

I got a tags in a column in the database that is saved with space separating each of them like so:

```
apple orange banana
```

I want to loop over them and put each on a separate line (between P tags). I got it somewhat running using the code below but the last line outputs the entire string too.

```
<p>apple</p>
<p>orange</p>
<p>banana</p>

apple orange banana (I do not want this line)
```

The code I use is this, how can I make it better / replace it so that I do not get the last line when I output the post?

```
        <% item.options.each(' ') do |item| %>

            <p><%= item %></p>

        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% (item.options.split(' ')).each do |item| %>

  <p><%= item %></p>

<% end %>
```

that should work well

Answer (score 3):

```
<% item.options.split(" ").each do |item| %>
  <p><%= item %>
<% end %>
```

or better yet you might create a virtual attribute in your model:

```
def tags do
  self.options.split(" ")
end
```

and then

```
<% item.tags.each do |tag| %>
  <p><%= tag %>
<% end %>
```